# using animated gif, Lottie animation or other alternatives, which is better for flutter?

Tags: flutter, animated-gif

I have very simple flutter main page and put electronic devices list. I just want to understand which is better for adding an animated icon near each device which showing the charging.

- an animated gif?
- a Lottie animated file?
- or any other alternative which better and commonly used for this kinda purpose.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to control the animation behaviour then go with [lottie](https://lottiefiles.com/), custom animation or [Rive](https://rive.app/). If you want static behaviour then go with gif.

Comment: so, I understand that since I need a purely static one, I can use "gif" and it will not make me trouble in iOS and Android platforms. Correct? thank you

Comment: Yes, It will work on all platforms. But if you use Lottie then performance will be good and you scan scale your animation to any size. Scaling will be tricky with gif because you might loose resolution in that. So i personally recommend Lottie.